# Write line including variables (string and int) in .txt file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a new line in my .txt file with 2 different variables.

```
void UpdateIPUserCNT(string IP, int CNT) //UPDATES COUNTER OF LOGGED USERS TO IP
{
    string temp; //saves 
    string tempIP = IP;
    char filename [120];
    sprintf(filename, "C:\\Server\\AntiCheat.txt");  

         int offset; 
    string line;
    ifstream Myfile; // File to read from
    Myfile.open (filename);

    ofstream OutPutFile;
  OutPutFile.open (filename);

    if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(!Myfile.eof())
        {
             getline(Myfile,line);
            if ((offset = line.find(tempIP, 0)) != string::npos) // If IP located in file
            {
                ///irelevant code///

            }
            else //ip not in list
            {
                
                ostringstream strg;
                strg<< CNT;
                string s1 = strg.str();
                std::string TempLine = ("%s %s", IP, s1);
                OutPutFile << TempLine;

                  


            }
        }

         Myfile.close();
    }
    else
   cout<<"Unable to open this file."<<endl;

}
```

Output text file "AntiCheat.txt":
1

Why its not writing the IP Address and only writing Counter? variable of IpAddress is defined when calling to function as string (For example: UpdateIPUserCNT(lpObj->Ip_addr,Counter); ).

Comment: Did you mean to attempt to write to `OutPutFile` after checking each line from `MyFile`?  Have you used your debugger to step through your code and see what's going on? What do you expect `TempLine`'s value to be?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for your reply, Should I just add another declaration of filename and open it?

Comment: `std::string TempLine = ("%s %s", IP, s1);` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. It's equivalent to `std::string TempLine = s1;` , it's not any kind of formatting directive.

Comment: @StephenNewell TempLine should be the temp variable for the new line.
The code searches the IP in the file, if its found it will update the counter- else, it will write new line that includes IP and Counter. (Example: 5.5.5.5 0)

Comment: As @IgorTandetnik mentioned and I tried to hint at, `TempLine` isn't doing what you think.  I'd suggest using a debugger and evaluating your algorithm.

Comment: A `std::cout << "Templine: '" << TempLine << "'\n";` would be informative.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `string TempLine = (IP + " 0\n");` fixed. but somehow all file changed instead of inserting new line. why?

Comment: Opening a file for writing clears its existing contents by default. Consult the documentation for flags you can pass to `ofstream::open`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `OutPutFile.open (filename,std::ios_base::app);` fixed the problem. How can I rewrite a specific line that includes the IP Address?

Comment: Unless all IP addresses are exactly the same number of characters (which I suppose you could arrange for, if you format them with leading zeros), you basically can't. You'd have to load the whole file into memory, update the data there, and write it back to the file.